# Referencing gridOptions from angular ternary operator

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angularjs-1.5

I have a ui-grid that has a toggleFilter button:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  ...  
  enableFiltering: false,
  ...
}

$scope.toggleFilter = function () {
  $scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering = !$scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering;
  $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
};

<div id="filter" ng-click="toggleFilter()">
  ({{$scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering ? "-" : "+"}}) {{$scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering ? "Dis" : "En"}}able Filtering
</div>
```

The toggle is working as expected and the text appears correct on load, but does not update with the change in `enableFiltering`.  What is missing to bind this property properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the $scope from your HTML.

```
({{gridOptions.enableFiltering ? "-" : "+"}}) {{gridOptions.enableFiltering ? "Dis" : "En"}}able Filtering
```

Working plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/vT6Ae8aJXrqonhq8ueKQ?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $scope.gridOptions = {
  
  enableFiltering: false,
  
}

$scope.toggleFilter = function () {
  $scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering = !$scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering;
  //$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
};
  
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="filter" ng-click="toggleFilter()">
    ({{gridOptions.enableFiltering ? "-" : "+"}}) {{gridOptions.enableFiltering ? "Dis" : "En"}}able Filtering
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That was the issue. Removed `$scope` from HTML.  Assuming you removed the `notifyDataChange` just for the example.  That is still needed to add/remove the filter inputs on the grid.

Comment: Yeah i commented "notifyDataChange"  just for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plunker with my approach: https://jsfiddle.net/frishi/psysv1ao/2/

I don't think your ternary expression is ever getting evaluated, you don't need to use the `$scope` to access properties on it in your view. That is implied.

Secondly, and this is my opinion, the ternary to control rendering of DOM is very unreadable. Please consider using `ng-if` or `ng-show` to implement conditional rendering of DOM.